# Loading C# Assembly System.Web.Extension for System.Web.Script.Serialization in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, assemblies

I am having difficulties getting Powershell to run my C# code using System.Web.Script.Serialization.  I am getting the error "The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".  I have already setup Powershell to use .Net 4.  The only thing I can think of that is causing this issue is that it is loading the client profile and not the full .Net 4 profile, but I am also not very proficient in either Powershell or C#.

Here's the Powershell script I am using, I omitted the C# code due to length.

```
$Assemblies = (
        "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
        "System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
        "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
        "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    )

$Source = @"
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Threading;

class DataMineAPI
{
   \\\\omitted 
}

class getUpsightData 
{
   \\\\omitted
}
"@

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 

New-Object DataMineAutomation.getUpsightData -Property @{
        queryFolder = "Path1";
        authFile = "File";
        downloadFolder = "Path2";
        logFolder = "Path3";
    }
```

Can anyone help me resolve this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like there is a typo, `$Assem` instead of `$Assemblies`. Try to use:

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assemblies -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
```

Comment: Oops, now I feel like an even bigger idiot.  Looks like it is now loading correctly, Thanks!  =)

Comment: @user3023763 no problem, it happens even to the best among us :P